# Could not find all sql connectors un standard logic app

Tags: azure-logic-app-standard

I have a standard logic app where I need to get the tables from azure Sql Server. When I was going through the Consumption and standard logic apps I found there are few connectors missing in standard when compared to consumption plan. Are there any alternatives to Get tables from Azure Sql Server in standard plan.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can navigate to your logic app and click on Azure connectors instead of Built-in Connectors.

[image]

[image]